# Printing values in a formatted way that has different formats depending on value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm still relatively new to python and was just wondering how to print values from a function that takes in a list as input and prints every value with a comma separated by every two values except -1 which it just prints by itself (assuming there will always be two values matched together if its not -1).

Some examples would be:
input: `[2,3,4,2,-1,4,3]`
output: `2 3, 4 2, -1, 4 3`

input: `[2,1,-1]`
output: `2 1, -1`

Every time a solution it feels like I'm overthinking it with while loops and if statements. Is there anyway for this to be faster and easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For situations where you may need to take multiple elements from a list in one iteration, an iterator is often a viable solution. Calling the built-in `iter()` on any iterable object (lists, strings, dicts, generators) will provide an iterator, which returns objects one at a time, dynamically, and which *cannot backtrack*. If you then assign an iterator to a variable and use that variable in a `for` loop, you can selectively call `next()` on it yourself to make the loop 'skip' elements:

```
inp = [2,3,4,2,-1,4,3]
inp_iter = iter(inp)
output = []
for elem in inp_iter:  # each iteration essentially calls next() on the iterator until there is no more next()
    if elem == -1:
        output.append(str(elem))
    else:
        # withdraw the next element from the iterator before the `for` loop does automatically
        # thus, the for loop will skip this element
        next_elem = next(inp_iter)
        output.append(f"{elem} {next_elem}")
print(', '.join(output))
# '2 3, 4 2, -1, 4 3'
```

You'll need to add error handling to this to deal with edge cases, but this should handle your immediate problem.

Comment: Thanks! this seems to have solved my problem, and introduced me to several new methods as well, but may I know what are the edge cases? 

It doesn't look like it will fail if given a extreme min or max, or am I misunderstanding the meaning of an edge case in python or are there parts of your code I may have overlooked?

Comment: @mhileas (1) what to do if -1 would be included in a pair, e.g. in the list `[2, -1, 3, 4]`. (2) what to do if the list is the wrong size and you get cut off in the middle of a pair, e.g. `[1]`, `[2, 3, -1, 4]`, etc. I use the terminology "edge case" to refer to more than just boundary-value problems - it's any 'unlikely' but still possible scenario that could cause the code to throw an error.